# stdcall and cdecl stack alignment size

Tags: stack, alignment, stdcall, cdecl

I have two questions:

1. Is the stack alignment for the stdcall calling convention *always* 4 bytes, or is it 4 for a 32 bit machine and 8 for a 64 bit machine?
2. What is the stack alignment size for cdecl?

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: I would like to add: Is there a way to get the alignment size? e.g. does sizeof(int) always work?

Comment: There is no `stdcall` on 64-bit Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Stack alignment for `stdcall` is always 4 bytes.

The stack alignment for `cdecl` is usually the size of the argument, but may be affected by compiler settings.